Surface integral of a vector field over the surface $x^{2} +y^{2} +( z-a)^{2} =a^{2}$ which lies inside $x^{2} +y^{2} =ay$ and underneath $z=a$
The exercise I'm solving (verbatim):

$$\mbox{Compute}\quad \iint _{\vec{S}}\frac{( x,y,z-a)}{\sqrt{2az-z^{2}}}\cdot{\rm d}\vec{S}
$$ where $\displaystyle \vec{S}$ is the part of the surface
$\displaystyle x^{2} +y^{2} +( z-a)^{2} =a^{2}$ which lies inside the
cylinder $\displaystyle x^{2} +y^{2} =ay$ and underneath the plane
$\displaystyle z=a$ oriented with outward pointing normal.

My attempt:
$$
\mbox{Let}\quad \vec F(x,y,z) = \frac{(x,\,y,\,z-a)}{\sqrt{2az-z^2}}
$$
Find the solid region enclosed by $S$ and then use Gauss-Divergence Theorem,
$$\iint_{\vec S}\vec{F}\cdot{\rm d}\vec{S} =
\iiint_{V} \nabla\cdot \vec{F}\,{\rm d}^{3}\vec{r}
$$
where the enclosure of $S$ is given by:
\begin{align}
V & = \{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+(z-a)^2<a^2; \, x^2+y^2<ay;\, z<a   \}
\\ & = \{(x,y,a-z):x^2+y^2+z^2<a^2;\, x^2+y^2<ay;\, z>0\}
\end{align}

I tried to put in spherical coordinates at this point, but I can't seem to manage the second condition.
I tried other substitutions as well, but it gets complicated.
This is a test question so it can't be computationally hard.

I feel stuck here. How do I approach this problem ?.

Use cylindrical coordinates. I doubt you want to use the divergence theorem. But you can simplify the problem by realizing that $(x,y,z-a)$ is a constant multiple of the unit normal.

I don't recommend using divergence theorem at all. Instead, notice that your unit normal vector is
$$\hat{n} = \frac{(x,y,z-a)}{a}$$
which implies
$$\iint_S\frac{(x,y,z-a)}{\sqrt{2az-z^2}}\cdot\frac{(x,y,z-a)}{a}dS = \iint_S\frac{a}{\sqrt{2az-z^2}}dS = \iint_S\frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dS$$
by leveraging the equation of the surface to get equivalent surface integrals. Now use the parametrization in terms of $x,y$ i.e.
$$\vec{r}(x,y) = \left(x,y,a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}\right)$$
which allows us to use the known shortcut for such standard "function" parameterizations $dS = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2+1}\:dxdy$:
$$I = \iint_{x^2+y^2\leq ay}\frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\cdot\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}dxdy$$
then swap to polar (cylindrical) coordinates
$$= \int_0^\pi\int_0^{a\sin\theta}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}}\:dr\:d\theta = 2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} a^2\theta\:d\theta = \boxed{\frac{\pi^2 a^2}{4}}$$
While maybe not necessary to understand the problem, the fact that you left the differentials out of every possible instance in your problem statement means you would have been much less likely to notice this rewriting trick since it hinges on the differentials.

Thank you! I thought you would need to fully parameterize the surface before finding a normal to it... I did not recognize that "is a part of the surface $x^2+y^2+(z-a)^2=a^2$"  allows me to determine the normal at a point $(x,y,z)$ using gradient vectors.

I did realize later after posting that cylindrical coordinates are best suit for this problem.
\begin{aligned}
S & =\left{( x,y,z) :\ x^{2} +y^{2} +( z-a)^{2} =a^{2} ,\ x^{2} +y^{2} < ay,\ z< a\right}\
& =\left{( r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta ,a-z) :\ r^{2} +z^{2} =a^{2} ,\ r^{2} < ar\sin \theta ,\ z >0\right}\
& =\left{\left( r\cos \theta ,r\sin \theta ,a-\sqrt{a^{2} -r^{2}}\right) :\ 0< \theta < \pi ,\ 0< r< a\sin \theta \right}
\end{aligned}

@Nothingspecial you don't want to parametrize in cylindrical from the start and then try to compute $dS$. Why? Compare the speed and computational effort of computing $dS(x,y)\to$polar coordinates vs cylindrical coordinates $\to dS(r,\theta)$.

Thanks! I realize the trick. Using the known shortcut for $\phi(x,y)=(x,y,f(x,y))$ i.e., $\lVert \phi_x\times \phi_y\rVert=\sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})^2}$ and parameterizing later saves me from computing a cross product because it's also known that $\mathrm dS(r,\theta) = r,\mathrm dr ,\mathrm d\theta$ (in cylindrical coordinates).
